# Java - Get array of name of day for current week

Tags: java, arrays, loops, calendar, dayofweek

What I am looking for is to create an array of the days of the week in java, starting from yesterday and go up to six days time as such

```
 String daysWeek[] = { "Yesterday", "Today", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
```

The first two elements of the array I want to return as Yesterday and Today.

At first this seemed like an easy task by using

```
currentDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

String daysList[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
            "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

String daysWeek[] = {"Yesterday", "Today", daysList[currentDay], daysList[currentDay+1], ...};
```

A note on above `daysList[currentDay]` will return tomorrow since the array of `daysList` starts at 0 i.e if `currentDay = 3` which says today is Tuesday then this will be `daysList[2]`.

But my problem lies in that if the currentDay is 7 which implies today is Saturday then `currentDay+1` which is tomorrow will be the eighth element of the array which doesn't exist.

Is there any which in I can loop round my numbers that if today is Wednesday or later then once `currentDay + x > 7`, set `currentDay` back to 1?

This all takes place in one method as is called `getDaysList(currentDay)` which returns the `daysWeek[]` array.

Comment: The answer of WChargin is right. I'd just like to know why you want to do that. Using arrays is often a sign of bad object oriented design. Maybe your code could be refactored. If you would explain your goal for storing the weekdays in an array maybe we could find a better solution (or understand that your solution is the best)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function of use to you here is the *modulo* (`%`) operator.

Basically, what the modulo operator does is take the remainder of the division, which is exactly what you want. (Remember back in fourth grade when "9 / 2" wasn't 4.5, but 4 remainder 1? This is that remainder part.)

So instead of having:

```
days[currentDay + x]
```

Use:

```
days[(currentDay + x) % 7]
```

Quick example on values returned by the modulo operator:

```
 0 % 7 = 0   (0 / 7 = 0 R0)
 1 % 7 = 1   (1 / 7 = 0 R1)
 6 % 7 = 6   (6 / 7 = 0 R6)
 7 % 7 = 0   (7 / 7 = 1 R0)
 8 % 7 = 1   (8 / 7 = 1 R1)
15 % 7 = 1   (15 / 7 = 2 R1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forgot about this notation.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
         .plusDays( 5 )
         .getDayOfWeek()
         .getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US )
```

## Details

Get your mind off the idea of array index relating to day-of-week.

Also, generally better to use a [modern collection object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) to gather your objects rather than a mere array.

Also, avoid the troublesome `Calendar` class. Now supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

First get the current date. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

We know the result for yesterday is `yesterday` so no need to calculate that date. If you do need the date, call `LocalDate::minusDays`.

We can ask each `LocalDate` for the name of its day by extracting a `DayOfWeek` enum object. That [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) know [its own name in any human language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) that you can specify via a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) object. So there is no need for you to track an array of template name-of-day strings. Tip: In [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), try to think of either (a) letting objects be smart take care of themselves, or (b) enlisting the aid of a helper object, rather than using basic arrays to do all the work yourself.

```
List<String> dayNames = new ArrayList<>( 7 ) ;  // Initialize to seven days of a week.
dayNames.add( "yesterday" ) ;
dayNames.add( "today" ) ;
for( int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i ++ ) {
    LocalDate ld = today.plusDays( i ) ;
    String dayName = ld.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US ) ;
    dayNames.add( dayName ) ;  // Add each of the five days remaining in a week.
}
```

Try this [code live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/Vkmj9j).

> [yesterday, today, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the remainder operator (`%`):

```
6 % 7 == 6
7 % 7 == 0
8 % 7 == 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
class Date {</p><br>
    public static void main(String args[]) { </p><br>
    // Monday 01/27/2019 15:07:53 AM
    System.out.println("Current Day: "+new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss a").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) );
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: It seems to be answering a different question from the one asked here.